# PySpark - Issue with CPU heavy cartesian join when using multiple join columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

**Background / scenario:**

I have two tables: One 1-2 million entry table with **transactions** of the form

```
TRX-ID , PROCESS-ID , ACTOR-ID
```

Additionally a **participant-lookup** (one of multiple categories of users of the system) table of the form

```
USER-ID , PARTICIPANT-ID
```

The **transaction** table is for historical reasons a bit messy. The PROCESS-ID can be a participant-id and the ACTOR-ID the user-id of a different kind of user. In some situations the PROCESS-ID is something else and the ACTOR-ID is the user-id of the participant.

I need to join the **transaction** and the **participant-lookup** table in order to get the participant-id for all transactions. I tried this in two ways.

(I left out some code steps in the snippets and focused on the join parts. Assume that df variables are data frames and the I select right columns to support e.g. unions.)

**First approach:**

```
transactions_df.join(pt_lookup_df, (transactions_df['actor-id'] == pt_lookup_df['user-id']) | (transactions_df['process-id'] == pt_lookup_df['participant-id']))
```

The code with this join is extrem slow. It ends up in my job running 45 minutes on a 10 instances AWS glue cluster with nearly 99% load on all executers.

**Second approach:**

I realised that some of the transactions already have the participant-id and I do not need to join for them. So I changed to:

```
transactions_df_1.join(pt_lookup_df, (transactions_df_1['actor-id'] == pt_lookup_df['user-id']))
transactions_df_2 = transactions_df_2.withColumnRenamed('process-id', 'participant-id')
transactions_df_1.union(transactions_df_2)
```

This finished in 5 minutes!

Both approaches give the correct results.

**Question**

I do not understand why the one is so slow and the other not. The amount of data excluded in the second approach is minimal. So transactions_df_2 has only a very small subset of the total data.

Looking at the plans, the affect is mainly around on Cartesian product that is done in approach 1 but not 2. So I assume, this is the performance bottleneck. I still do not understand how this can lead to 40 minutes differences in compute time.

Can someone give explanations?

Would a Cartesian product in the DAG be in general a warning sign in Spark?

**Summary**

It seems that a join with multiple columns in the condition triggers an extrem slow Cartesian product operation. Should I have done a broadcast operation on the smaller data set to avoid this?

DAG approach 1

[image: DAG approach 1 (40 minutes)]

[image]

[image]

DAG approach 2

[image: DAG approach 2 (5 minutes)]

[image]

Comment: it looks like, as suggested by @Yoan_B._M.Sc, different shuffle strategy results in much higher (10x) number of tasks which eventually leads to 10x time difference. GC doesnt look outrageous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a `Cartesian Product join` and a regular `join` do not involve the same data shuffling process. Even thought the amount of data is similar the amount of shuffling is different.

This [article](https://www.hadoopinrealworld.com/how-does-cartesian-product-join-work-in-spark/) explains where is the extra shuffling coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand that they differ but I still find the performance and cluster load difference extrem. I assume that there are situation where one can not avoid the Cartesian product and I would for sure not expect the some operation to take 40 minutes on a relational data base.

Would it in general be better to decompose the join into multiple sub joins and one union? Let's say I have even 3 columns I need to "OR" join.

Comment: I would have assumed that in the multi column join scenario spark just partitions by all the join columns combined. So I already do not understand why my operation lead to a cartesian join at all. In this article here its mentioned the cartesian join always happens if more than "table-nr minus 1" columns are involved. 

https://george-jen.gitbook.io/data-science-and-apache-spark/issue-from-running-cartesian-join-query

Somebody can refresh my db-lecture knowledge why this is the case?

Comment: To answer my own thought from above: Of course, if I join with an OR condition over multiple columns, then its not possible to partition by the column combination, due to the OR. So it must end up with a cross product.

Comment: I can't tel you why it's taking 40mn and not 25mn, but if we are talking about optimization in a situation where you are using cross product or join, repartioning the data before MIGHT lead to some speed up and reduce shuffle. Idk if breaking it down in multiple join would be faster down the line, you might still incur several shuffle.

Comment: Regarding the shuffle: Is the shuffling actually also surfacing as heavy CPU load? Since this part was irritating for me when checking the logs. There was not a lot of data send around. I attributed the load first to some other parts of the code, until with some try and error I narrowed it down to the cross-product.

I assume then that the recreation of the partitions on the machine and the construction of the actual intermediate cross product result set is what keeps the machine busy. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would expect shuffling to generate CPU load but I cannot tell if the main of the activity is coming from there.